# Dynamic WHERE clause in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, dynamic, ms-access-2007, where-clause

I am trying to get the following result in a query.

```
SELECT * FROM rosterTbl
WHERE (IIF( ISNULL([Forms]![ReportsGUI]![cmbCounsellor]), rosterTbl.CounsellorID<>null,rosterTbl.CounsellorID=[Forms]![ReportsGUI]![cmbCounsellor]
```

I know the above query is incorrect but I need the result: If `cmbCounsellor` is `Null` Then all counsellors Else specific counsellor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way to do this within query:

```
SELECT * from rosterTbl 
WHERE [Forms]![ReportsGUI]![cmbCounsellor] IS  NULL
OR 
rosterTbl.CounsellorID 
= ([Forms]![ReportsGUI]![cmbCounsellor])
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like this will work:

```
="SELECT * FROM rosterTbl WHERE CounsellorID " & IIf(IsNull([Forms]![ReportsGUI]![cmbCounsellor], "IS NOT NULL", "= " & [Forms]![ReportsGUI]![cmbCounsellor])
```

### edit re: comments

In this particular case the WHERE condition will be used to control the records to be included in a report, so the compete SELECT statement is not really required. Instead, the "WHERE" clause can be passed to the report via the `WhereCondition` argument of `DoCmd.OpenReport`, something like this:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "MyReport", acViewPreview, , "CounsellorID " & IIf(IsNull([Forms]![ReportsGUI]![cmbCounsellor], "IS NOT NULL", "= " & [Forms]![ReportsGUI]![cmbCounsellor])
```

Comment: Where should I put this line? After Where clause?

Comment: @UmairAnsari What do you intend to do with the SELECT statement? In other words, how are you actually going to *use* it?

Comment: I am sending a parameter from Form and generating a Report. I want to generate 2 Reports from 1 Query. 1 Report is for specific Counsellor and other is the summary of all counsellor.

Comment: @UmairAnsari ...so you will eventually be using `DoCmd.OpenReport` in VBA to open the report?

Comment: Yes i am using DoCmd.OpenReport

Comment: I am using multiple statements in WHERE clause with the CousellorID. Do I need to pass full WHERE clause via form or only the counsellorID statement?

Comment: @UmairAnsari You'll need to pass the whole WHERE clause, omitting the WHERE keyword.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got the result within Query. Check my answer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40287/discussion-between-umair-ansari-and-gord-thompson)